# How to fix problems with Promise arguments types in Node.js application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

In **Node.js** application I make 2 sql queries by [sequelize](https://sequelize.readthedocs.io/en/v3/) library. Then I combine result of both requests in Promise.

```
router.post('/notification', function(request, response) {
    const survey_id = request.query.survey_id;

    const employees = sequelize.query('SELECT ARRAY_AGG (EMPLOYEE) AS EMPLOYEES FROM SURVEYS_EMPLOYEES_RELATIONSHIP WHERE SURVEY_ID = :survey_id AND STATUS = FALSE', {
        replacements: {
            survey_id: survey_id,
        },
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    });

    const templates = sequelize.query('SELECT TEMPLATE FROM TEMPLATES WHERE ID = 1', {
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    });

    Promise.all([employees, templates]).then(responses => {
        console.log(responses[0][0]["employees"]);
        console.log(responses[1][0]["template"]);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
});
```

I have such warning when run application:

```
Argument type [Promise, Promise] is not assignable to parameter type [(PromiseLike<T>|T), ...]
```

How I can fix this warning? It seems like something wrong with this part of code:

`.all([employees, templates])`.

Comment: `It seems like something wrong with this part of code` well, no, because Promise.all will take an array of anything without any complaints - of course, it doesn't look like you're actually using javascript

Comment: `it doesn't look like you're actually using javascript` what exactly you mean? I am confused. It's simple `Node/Express` application. What can you offer?

Comment: `PromiseLike<T>` doesn't look like regular javascript - looks like there's some typescript involvement there based on that error